# docker run with ENTRYPOINT containing a variable

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a private git repository on [github.com](http://github.com) and I want to automate the `docker build` process using a `Dockerfile`. I naively thought the best place to have the `Dockerfile` is in the root folder of my repo. Example:

```
git clone ssh://git@github.com/avilella/bioboxes_playground
cd bioboxes_playground
ls Dockerfile
Dockerfile
```

So the files in the repo folder are:

```
[hpenvy15 bioboxes_playground] $ tree -Difts
.
[      18027 Mar  3 14:58]  ./LICENSE
[         22 Mar  3 14:58]  ./README.md
[        825 Mar  4 11:59]  ./Dockerfile
[       4096 Mar  4 11:59]  ./src
[         74 Mar  4 11:59]  ./src/hello_world.c
```

So for external dependencies, I am installing them with `apt-get install` or downloading the tar.gz and installing them during `docker build`.

I found out from a previous question how to add local files to the image (called the "context" in Dockerfile): http://kimh.github.io/blog/en/docker/gotchas-in-writing-dockerfile-en/#add_and_understanding_context_in_dockerfile

I added a simple `src/hello_world.c` example which is in the repo, and I want to compile during `docker build`. See below:

EDITED: added `WORKDIR` now

```
FROM debian:wheezy
MAINTAINER Foo Bar, foo@bar.com

ENV ORG foo
ENV APP bar
ENV INSTALL_DIR /opt/${ORG}/${APP}

ENV PACKAGES wget binutils make csh g++ sed gawk perl zlib1g-dev 
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ${PACKAGES}

ENV SEQTK https://github.com/avilella/seqtk/archive/sgdp.tar.gz

ENV THIRDPARTY_DIR ${INSTALL_DIR}/thirdparty

RUN mkdir -p ${THIRDPARTY_DIR}
RUN cd ${THIRDPARTY_DIR}

# SEQTK

RUN mkdir -p ${THIRDPARTY_DIR}/seqtk && cd ${THIRDPARTY_DIR}/seqtk &&\
    wget --quiet --no-check-certificate ${SEQTK} --output-document - |\
    tar xzf - --directory . --strip-components=1 && \
    make

# COMPILE HELLO_WORLD

ADD src/hello_world.c ${INSTALL_DIR}/hello_world.c

RUN gcc ${INSTALL_DIR}/hello_world.c -o ${INSTALL_DIR}/hello_world

WORKDIR ${INSTALL_DIR}
ENTRYPOINT ["./hello_world"]
```

My issue currently is that my defined `ENTRYPOINT` does not work
because `INSTALL_DIR` is an ENV variable. I can hard-code it to
`/opt/foo/bar/hello_world`, and then it works:

```
$ sudo docker run -i foo                                                                                                                                  
exec: "./hello_world": stat ./hello_world: no such file or directory2015/03/04 15:43:37 Error response from daemon: Cannot start container cd39493be9f40a8714cbc1e503a1f172e2e5dc485881d0b5e34322fbb2f71380: exec: "./hello_world": stat ./hello_world: no such file or directory
```

This works:

```
$ sudo docker run --entrypoint='/opt/foo/bar/hello_world' -i foo                                                                                          
Hello World
```

Any ideas how to make the ENTRYPOINT work in my example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ENTRYPOINT` doesn't do ENV replacement, but [`WORKDIR` does](http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#environment-replacement):

```
WORKDIR ${INSTALL_DIR}
ENTRYPOINT ./hello_world
```

But I wonder why you want to have the INSTALL_DIR as a variable? If you weren't using containers, you'd do this so that `/opt/foo/bar` and `/opt/foo/baz` and `/opt/qux/bar` can all coexist. But if each of these is in a separate container, then they can all live at `/opt/app`.

Comment: Perhaps he likes the fact that he can define a install dir by orgname and appname. Other than that, having to change those vars would mean that the whole dockerfile will rebuild (all caches invalidate). Doesn't seem very usefull.

Comment: I see. I now updated it to the last two lines being the ones in your example, but it still does not work for me. Hard-coded does work.

Comment: You're using the JSON form, but I wrote my example in non-JSON because I'm relying on the shell to use the relative path. You could say `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash","./hello_world"]` and I think that would be the same.